# Using VSCode with a Raspberry Pi 1

Tags: visual-studio-code, raspberry-pi, remote-access

I'm trying to set-up Raspberry Pi 1 with VSCode so I could run code remotely on it. I've installed VSCode on the Pi, but when trying to launch it with the 'code' command, I get an 'Illegal instruction' error.

I tried connecting remotely from my Windows workstation, but I got an error saying that "the remote's host architecture isn't supported".

My question is, is it possible to install VSCode on the original Pi? If not, what IDE do you use to work remotely on it, besides ssh and VNC?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[According to VS Code's official site, Raspberry Pi 1 is not supported.](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/setup/raspberry-pi#_system-requirements)

> First-generation Raspberry Pi modules and Raspberry Pi Zero are not supported as they only include an ARMv6 CPU.

Seems to me Raspberry Pi 1 has very low hardware and I'm sure that it will give you hard times when you codding. If you wanna use it anyway, you may continue with a browser-based editor like [AWS cloud9](https://aws.amazon.com/cloud9/?nc1=h_ls).

Comment: Thank you, I'll try it out!

Comment: Also, https://vscode.dev/  looks promising!